# Max ram for Acer Aspire one D255

Tags: netbook, acer-aspire-one

I can't seem to find what the max amount of ram is supported on the Acer Aspire one D255. It came with 1gb, and I see that most netbooks support up to 2gb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"". The D255 will support 2GB of RAM (there’s a single slot inside) but it’s not especially easy to open up the casing. Happily you’ll only ever do it once.""

http://www.slashgear.com/acer-aspire-one-d255-review-28110853/

Answer (score 2):

While the Slashgear site certainly seems to suggest that a single RAM slot leads to no more than 2GB of memory, [DDR3 RAM is available up to 4GB on a single module and could in the future go as high as 16GB on a single module](https://superuser.com/questions/229271/do-ddr3-modules-come-in-sizes-greater-than-2gb).

Therefore I'd say the question is still open. Perhaps Slashgear is wrong or just sloppily worded. Perhaps there is a 2GB limit but if so it's not because a single DDR3 slot can't have more memory plugged into it.

**UPDATE**

It turns out the [Intel Atom N550 *is* limited to 2GB of RAM](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=50154), so the processor is the limiting factor rather than the number of RAM slots.

Answer (score 1):

your acer aspire d255 is most likely a 32bit system. If its windows 7 starter it will only allow you to have 2gb of physical memory. You can change that by changing settings in your boot menu though.

Comment: How do you change the boot menu setting?