# Do DDR3 modules come in sizes greater than 2GB?

Tags: memory, ddr3

The standard answer to how much RAM i can install in my Acer Aspire One D255 is "2 gigs" and the standard reason given is "because it only has one RAM slot". Does this mean DDR3 RAM modules only go up to 2gigs? Do bigger ones exist or is there somethig in the DDR3 spec that limits the size? Wikipedia was no help this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newegg seems to provide an [ample number of examples](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007609+600006178+600000399&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=381&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=) of 4GB laptop DDR3 memory, which seem to be available across the board (at the two clock speeds).

To your specific questions:

> Does this mean DDR3 RAM modules only go up to 2gigs?

No. It probably just means that your vendor (or whoever is answering your question) does not have access to 4GB sticks of RAM. I haven't dealt with aftermarket laptop memory, but installing two different capacity RAM sticks shouldn't be problematic.

> Do bigger ones exist or is there somethig in the DDR3 spec that limits the size?

No.

Comment: Do you know if there is any maximum size or a maximum currently size currently on the market?

Comment: 4 GB is the limit on the market today; [16 GB is the theoretical limit, per the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM). It's also the most memory that anyone in position to ask the question would possibly need. It is quite rare for a laptop to have applications that require >4 GB. If you find 4 GB insufficient for your purposes, you may want to consider purchasing a specialized server-machine for substantially better performance for cost.